# Redirect Capital Letter URLs to lower case urls

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, squarespace, capitalization

I've noticed a couple of times that in Google Webmaster Tools that I have crawl errors based on capital letters in my URLs.

My URL's are all lower case when I build the pages, but there are proper nouns in the names, so this may be causing the error.

ex. [/california-insurance-license](https://staterequirement.com/california-insurance-license) could be /California-insurance-license

Is there some sort of redirect that I can do? If so, would I have to set all variations of capitalization up manually with 301's, because I can see that taking 17.3 years to complete.

If you have a solution, or recommendation, feel free to jump in.

Oh, and I'm on SquareSpace, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!